# Tear off widgets in web framework?

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

Is it possible, and do any frameworks exist that support tear-off widgets in a web browser? i.e. In Visual Studio, you can take any of the windows and pull it out of the main window to create a separate floating window.

We have a native application that we're porting parts of to the web. Currently we have the ability to take some of the windows and drag them out of the main window to create a separate window. We would like to support something similar to that in our web based version of the app.

We're not currently tied to any particular javascript framework for the UI, so any insight into the current state of Web UI frameworks with respect to this functionality would be appreciated.

Comment: check this https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout (it is for React framework)

Comment: That is a grid layout. We're looking for tear off tool windows.

Comment: You're running in a browser yes? There are none that I've ever heard of. Funny thing is that you could do it. It would take some elbow grease to figure out the mechanics. First off your "widgets" would have to be designed to be able to stand alone in a new browser window.

Comment: Which widgets do you mean to tear off?

Comment: Different Presentation layers often require rethinking your app design. Though it is both technically feasible and possible, I really wonder if you are designing your app with the web in mind. Think for example about mobile clients, where each torn off widget would rather become a separate tab. This might not be what the user would be after. I would rather check into allowing minimization/hiding of tool panels and re-ordering them on your screen than tearing them off. Some trade of need to be made when porting apps, that's the nature of things :)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to achieve, but here is a blunt example with jQuery:

```js
function popup(id) {
  $('#' + id + '-pop').prop('disabled', true);

  var popup = window.open('', 'popup', 'resizable=yes');
  var content = $('#' + id).detach();
  $(popup.document.body).append(content);

  popup.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $('#' + id + '-pop').prop('disabled', false);
    content.appendTo($('#' + id + '-parent'));
  };
}
```

```css
.tearable-parent {
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="t1-parent" class="tearable-parent">
    <div id="t1">
      <span>This is tearable.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="t1-pop" onclick="popup('t1')">Pop me up</button>
</body>
```

You can not run the example here, as popup is not allowed, but here is a [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/35yor2dp/1) where you can try it. When you close the popup, it moves the content back. Please note that you may need your own extra wiring if you are planning to move dynamic content around.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible on the web.

I think it is a bad idea. Here's why:

Pop ups, the mechanism to spawn new windows, will potentially be blocked,

it is uncommon practice, so it will break user expectations,

it can take time to make work properly

An alternative would be to have virtual windows inside a web page, what I mean is to make something similar, except using divs inside a page, that can be minimized and moved but inside the page only

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Walle. The "virtual windows" approach is better than using popups. I would take a look at Sencha and their Ext JS platform: [Sencha Ext JS](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/#overview)

I've never used it myself as it's proprietary, however the demos look very promising. Here's one showing "virtual windows": [Web Desktop](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/classic/desktop/index.html)

Comment: It is a fun technology to work with, but requires a developer to rethink their approach (as with many other frameworks). They have a very declarative approach and their documentation is not the best, however I worked with it a year or 2 ago and once you get the hang of it, it's a very nice framework. If you are willing to pay for it, that's another thing, many other free frameworks provide similar technologies

Answer (score 0):

If you are porting a windows app to a web app (which I do for the last couple of years) there is nothing on the market comparable to extjs, especially if it is a enterprise application.